# Same or different xml namespaces?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

In my project, there are lots of XML files of various sort, like XSDs, WSDLs, parameter maps etc. They all receive a generated namespace by the IDE, but the namespaces are not unique (across projects - elements with the same name get the same namespace) nor descriptive (or confusing - they all begin with "http://www.ibm.com/...", even though they define my own entities, not those of IBM). Namespace refactoring is necessary, then.

My doubts are the following:

1) Should every element have its own namespace, or should related elements share their namespaces? For instance,

- Should SOAP request and response messages belong to the same namespace, or should they have their own namespace?
- Should WSDL and related XSD use the same target namespace, or different?

For example:

```
http://www.xarx.com/xmlns/TheProject/Administration/wsdl/StartProcess
http://www.xarx.com/xmlns/TheProject/Administration/xsd/StartProcessRequest
http://www.xarx.com/xmlns/TheProject/Administration/xsd/StartProcessResponse
```

or everything into

```
http://www.xarx.com/xmlns/TheProject/Administration
```

2) All generated namespaces that will be publicly visible must be corrected, sure. But what about the ones that are internal to the project - is their refactoring a waste of time? They might appear in the administration console or in logs, and wrong namespaces there could be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've tried to use the same XML namespace in WebSphere ESB for all related elements, and here are my experiences:

All related elements can use the same namespace, the IDE and the compiler do not bother. Elements with different purpose usually have different names, so they cause no name collisions. But the IDE generates lots of XML files, and it sometimes happens that the generated elements have the same name as what you would like to use. (Typically XXX_Request and XXX_Response are names generated by the Websphere Integration Developer into derived WSDL files, so we had to use XXX_Req and XXX_Res for our purposes instead.)